# How can I split a numerical column depending on the value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a column into two separate columns based on whether the value in column A is true or false.

Example:

```
A       X   
True    3   
False   6   
True    2   
False   4   

A       Y   Z
True    3   
False       6
True    2   
False       4
```

I've found examples online of this with string manipulation, but I'm working with integers.

I can combine the columns by df[Y] + df[Z], but can't find a way to split them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df.A, df.X, np.nan)
df['Z'] = np.where(~df.A, df.X, np.nan)
```

Or [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with 
[`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Y'] = df.X.where(df.A)
df['Z'] = df.X.mask(df.A)
```

---

```
print (df)
       A  X    Y    Z
0   True  3  3.0  NaN
1  False  6  NaN  6.0
2   True  2  2.0  NaN
3  False  4  NaN  4.0
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `()` for masks:

```
df['Y'], df['Z'] = np.select([(df.A, ~df.A)], [df.X], default=np.nan)

print (df)
       A  X    Y    Z
0   True  3  3.0  NaN
1  False  6  NaN  6.0
2   True  2  2.0  NaN
3  False  4  NaN  4.0
```

---

If want empty strings change `NaN`s to `''`, but if next processing is necessary then it failed:

```
df['Y'], df['Z'] = np.select([(df.A, ~df.A)], [df.X], default='')
```

Or:

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df.A, df.X, '')
df['Z'] = np.where(~df.A, df.X, '')
print (df)
       A  X  Y  Z
0   True  3  3   
1  False  6     6
2   True  2  2   
3  False  4     4
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I would then like to do this again with another column (W), for the opposite (fill na)? E.g df['Y'] = df.W.where(~df.A) without replacing the column.

Comment: @JR1 - Then use `df['W'] = df.Y.fillna(df.Z)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Y'] = df['X'][df['A']==True]
df['Z'] = df['X'][df['A']==False]
```